# Recommended way to do this in Object Orientated PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I want to fill a html select element for modification of data.

Is the following code a good idea to get all possible variations (fetched from a database) of a certain class? Or is there some sort of standard way to do the same?

```
class Foo{

    public static $foo;
    public static $all_foos;

    public static __construct() {

        self::$foo = null;
        self::$all_foos = array();

    }

    public static get_foo_by_id( $id ) {

        self::$foo = "foo" . $id;

    }

    public static get_all_foos() {

        $array_foo_ids = array( 1, 2 ); // id's fetched from database

        foreach( $array_foos as $foo_id ) {

            new Foo;
            Foo::get_foo_by_id( $foo_id );
            self::$all_foos[] = Foo;

        }

    }

}

$foo = new Foo;
Foo::get_all_foos();

var_dump( $foo->all_foos );
```

Comment: If the code works and you just want to know if there is a better way, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Code obviously does not work. I see at least one foo in error in the foo in pseudo code

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry mate, that comment was aimed at the foo in OP

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Hehe, there you go.. me just assuming things again! :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No harm, no foul. :)  I am all foo'd out now, off to a answerable question

Comment: Haven't tested this code obviously, I only want to do it the right way and try to learn if there is a standard way of doing this.